# How do I get screen sizes from a service?

Tags: android

From an activity I would do it like this

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int x = display.getWidth();
```

Yet a service ( keyboard ) doesn't seem to support it... any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Since the service runs in the background, away from the window display, I don't believe there is a way, but if it is important then just have the activity pass that information to the service.

Answer (score 0):

Use getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)

```
Display display = ( (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) ).getDefaultDisplay();
int x = display.getWidth();
int y = display.getHeight();
```